Handling events on Metronic Tailwind CSS components in Blazor
I am attempting to use Metronic (9.x) with Blazor, and have started a project based on the official sample found here: https://github.com/keenthemes/metronic-tailwind-html-integration/tree/638f04486f737a6c5b86edf51666b8eb72469fb8/metronic-tailwind-blazor-server
Although I have to point out, this hardly qualifies as a "Blazor" sample since it is really just html, served up with Blazor. That is exactly the problem though, since I cannot figure out how to do something as simple as create a dropdown with clickable items that can be captured with @onchange or @onclick events.
For example, if I look at the official Metronic Tailwind CSS docs for Dropdown (https://keenthemes.com/metronic/tailwind/docs/components/dropdown) and Menu (https://keenthemes.com/metronic/tailwind/docs/components/menu/) then I was hoping to be able to do something like this:
@page "/stacks"

<PageTitle>MyPage</PageTitle>

<div class="dropdown" data-dropdown="true" data-dropdown-trigger="click">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-light">
        Show Dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content w-full max-w-56 py-2">
        <div class="menu menu-default flex flex-col w-full">
        @foreach (var myItem in allItems)
        {
            <div class="menu-item">
                <a class="menu-link" @onclick="HandleMyClickEvent">
                    <span class="menu-icon">
                        <i class="ki-outline ki-badge">
                        </i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="menu-title">
                        Menu item @myItem.Name
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private List<MyClass> allItems = new();

    public class MyClass
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        allItems = new List<MyClass>()
        {
            new MyClass()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "foo",
            },
            new MyClass()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "bar",
            }
        };

    }
    
    private async Task HandleMyClickEvent(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event has been triggered!");
    }    

}

However, the @onclick delegation does not trigger. In fact it doesn't look like any of the built-in Blazor delegators (such as @onchange etc.) can be triggered anywhere, so I assume that I am supposed to somehow tap into the built-in metronic events. (see https://keenthemes.com/metronic/tailwind/docs/components/menu#events).
How am I supposed to set this up?
